# ANDROID: Context Menu does not show

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have an activity.
In the activity i have this in onCreate:

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      settings = (GlobalSettings) getApplication();
      mappingServiceContent = settings.getMappingServiceContent();
      mapView = settings.getMapView();
      if (mapView == null)
      {
          mapView = new RMapView(RCoordinateSystemFactory.createFromCrsCode("EPSG:2170"));
          settings.setMapView(mapView);
          settings.isFirstTime = true;
      }
      else
      {
          settings.isFirstTime = false;
      }

      RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
      myMapView = new MyMapView(this, this.getWindowManager(), settings);  
      zoomControls = new ZoomControls(this);
      registerForContextMenu(myMapView );

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mapViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
      relativeLayout.addView(myMapView, mapViewLayoutParams);

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoomControlsLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        zoomControlsLayoutParams.addRule (RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        zoomControlsLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
      relativeLayout.addView(zoomControls,zoomControlsLayoutParams);

      zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(final View v) {
            myMapView.ZoomIn();
          }
        });

        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(final View v) {
            myMapView.ZoomOut();
          }
        });


      myMapView.setClickable(true);
      myMapView.setEnabled(true);

      setContentView(relativeLayout);
   }
```

MyMapView is a View created like this:

```
public class MyMapView extends View
```

In my activity i have added:

```
   @Override  
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
       super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
       menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
       menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");  
   }
```

But the context menu never gets fired if i hold my finger on the screen.
I must be missing something ... can some1 please help me out?

regards.

Comment: There is not a problem with the onCreateContext..(). Please post the entire onCreate()

Comment: Are you overriding onTouchEvent in MyMapView? If so, please post that code. You might swallow the long-press.

Comment: yes i am. im using onTouch there to pan/zoom map !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are just missing sg. AFAIK your code should work. If you cannot get a solution, try AlertDialog, it is the same (or looks and behaves the same, idk).

```
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {        
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
    }
 });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

The code is from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: i need a menu .. with items ... clickable for additional actions :/. In "MyMapView" i have onTouch .. and if i just needed dialog i could calculater difference between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP and fire up a dialog ... but thats not what i need.

Comment: OK then i don't know what you need. The code i provided shows you a clickable menu. I used both this code and the one from your link yesterday and they both show the same menu.

Comment: oh sorry man, i didnt notice onClickListener :) will give it a shoot if i dont get contextMenu working !

Comment: it works ... but i have to calculate the difference between motion events to fire it up ... abit messy to have that in onTouch on MyMapView but at least it works. rochdev has a point in my question comment ... i guess onTouch messes something up for longClick...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you are using onTouch in MyMapView you could do something like this. Just return false in the events and it wont be consumed.

```
public class MyButtonMenuAndTouch extends Button {

    private static final String TAG = MyButtonMenuAndTouch.class.getName();

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public MyButtonMenuAndTouch(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.setText("My button with context menu and touch");

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());        

        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {                 
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        this.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLongClickEvent");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {          
            Log.d(TAG, "onFling() - MyGestureDetector");
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDown() - MyGestureDetector");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSingleTapUp() - MyGestureDetector");
            return true;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a `menuInflater` to inflate in a  given resource menu see this example it will be useful [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: im a bit confused ... does this mean i have to create an XML for the context menu? I thought i would be using "system" context menu ...

Comment: yes u should define the layout this used to show the context menu in this case u r not defining the layout see the example context menu   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

Comment: ok i will try it ... but can you just explain why this code is not working? i took it from http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/ and it seemed like a perfect solution

Comment: i created a simple layout for the menu and used menuInflater ... yet still nothing happens.